# ps grep show matching word

Tags: android, adb, ps

I am trying to find if a process with a matching word exists in adb shell?

I search and tried many but the closest I found was using [`pgrep <word>`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612315/how-do-i-search-for-a-process-by-name-without-using-grep)

```
shell@rolex:/ $ pgrep -f whatsapp                                              
29775
```

But that shows only process id and not the other columns you see when only doing ps

What I want

```
shell@rolex:/ $ some ps/grep command which shows full process based on partial keyword 
USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   WCHAN              PC  NAME    
u0_a64    29775 627   1021744 37524 SyS_epoll_ 0000000000 S com.whatsapp
```

Answer (score 0):

`pgrep` will only give you the process id. I think what you really want is

```
ps aux | grep <term>
```